# Calculating a Binomial Expression

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution

Hello everyone I am a student in high school and I have a question how can I calculate this expression: $\binom{6n}{0}-\binom{6n}{3}+\binom{6n}{6}-\binom{6n}{9}+\cdots +\binom{6n}{6n}$ ?

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know? Where is this question from? I am voting to close this question due to lack of context.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

Consider $(1-x)^{6n}$. Put in $x=1,\omega,\omega^2$ where $\omega =\exp(i2\pi/3)$, add the expressions and divide by $3$.

Comment: Thanks you but I dont know what is exp. Do you know a simpler solution?

Comment: The notation $\exp(x)$ is simply for the exponential function, $e^x$.

Comment: I didn't learn it

Comment: There is another way to solve the question?

Comment: There might be a combinatorial approach to solving this but that would be more complicated it seems.

Comment: I think it should be $e^{i 2\pi /3}$

Comment: @Abhinav Made the necessary edits.